# In a game between two clients over a network. How to close both client windows when one of them quits?

Tags: java, session, networking, network-programming

so I am looking for a way in which two clients are playing a game over a network, that when one of them quits the entire session closes.

I understand I have to close the socket and catch an IOException and then exit, but exactly how would I do this? I tried doing this

```
try {
    // Some data/messages received etc
} catch ( IOException e ) {
    // Exits after interruption
} finally {
    try {
        socket.close();
        System.exit( NORM_PRIORITY );
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        System.err.println( "ERROR: Cannot close socket" );
        System.exit(1); // Exit with error
    }
}
```

But this closes ALL sessions including the server. What exactly am I doing wrong? I tried running the clients and server on different jvm so it may not be because of System.exit(..)

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Are the two clients connected to each other? Are they connected to a central server? And you need to *check* the exception, to see if it's a peer closing or an actual error.

Comment: They are connected via a central server. I'll look into peer closing thanks for that.

Comment: So far the only way I've found is by catching an IOException or out.errorCheck but I want to close both windows as soon as one of them exits. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, writing the answer for the sake if anyone else has the same question.

So I made a helper method which when a client exits the game, it would send a message to the Model indicating it exited and to close its socket, and then the model would redirect that message to ALL clients requesting for them to close their socket and dispose of the GUI.